# No Value showing in Gallery Price Column

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

Trying to figure out what is missing? Every-time a user submit a new order the price should show up. But is showing the value has "0"

**Price** Columns Type is **Currency**

> [image]

[image]

This is the code to create a new collection

```
    NewForm(Form1);ClearCollect(PinteyBowesCollection, {Category: "", SubCategory: "", ProductName: "", Quantity: "", Price: 0});Navigate(Order_Screen);ScreenTransition.Cover;Clear(PinteyBowesCollection)
```

This is the code to PATCH

```
Patch(PinteyBowesCollection,Defaults(PinteyBowesCollection),{Category:drpCategory.SelectedText.Result,SubCategory:drpSubCategory.SelectedText.Result,ProductName:drpProductName.SelectedText.Result,Price:Value(txtPrice.Text)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out

```
NewForm(Form2);ClearCollect(PitneyBowesCollection, {Category: "", SubCategory: "", ProductName: "", Quantity: "", Price: 0});Navigate('Order Screen');Clear(PitneyBowesCollection)
```

**SharePoint list: Price Column = Type: Currency**